# Angular5 click event using dynamic html

Tags: html, angular5

```js
send(){

 const el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.eventlist');
   if (el) {
     el.addEventListener('click', this.accounType.bind(this));
   }

}
accounType(id, message) {
 console.log(id, message);
}
```

```html
component.html

<ul >
 <div *ngFor="let chat of chatContent; let i = index">
  <li [ngClass]="chat.type=='user' ? 'other': 'self'" [class]="'chat'+i">
    <span *ngIf="chat.msgType=='text'" [innerHtml]=sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(chat.message)></span>
  </li>
 </div>
</ul>


Dynamic HTML 

    <div class="btn-primary col-49 btn-inicio eventlist" (click)="accounType(1,2)">Coffee</div>
    <div class="btn-primary col-49 btn-inicio eventlist" (click)="accounType(1,4)">Tea</div>
```

Dynamically created html in the chat box, There is a set of buttons, click event is not working in that buttons

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: While click the button accounType(id, message) is not calling.

Comment: its two argument and you have define with one argument

Comment: I checked without arguments, still its not working.

Comment: where `send()` call from

Comment: After listing the records send will call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182261/discussion-between-sanith-and-bhargav-chudasama).

Comment: error: accounType is not defined